# Function not found, though package installed an attached

Tags: r, package

im tryring to run `dcc.est` from the `ccgarch`-package.
Even though I installed the package and attached it with `library(ccgarch)`, I get the following error:

```
library(ccgarch)
dcc <- dcc.est(dvar, param)
```

> Error: could not find function "dcc.est"

I also tried the following:

```
dcc <- ccgarch::dcc.est(dvar, param)
```

> Error: object 'dcc.est' is not exported by 'namespace:ccgarch'

Accordingly to the vignette of ccgarch version 0.2.3 (https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/ccgarch/ccgarch.pdf) , `dcc.est` is part of the package. What am I doing wrong?

See my `sessionInfo`below:

```
> sessionInfo()
R version 3.3.2 (2016-10-31)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows >= 8 x64 (build 9200)

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=German_Germany.1252  LC_CTYPE=German_Germany.1252    LC_MONETARY=German_Germany.1252
[4] LC_NUMERIC=C                    LC_TIME=German_Germany.1252    

attached base packages:
[1] parallel  stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
 [1] pracma_1.9.5          kerdiest_1.2          evir_1.7-3            chron_2.3-48          date_1.2-35          
 [6] fGarch_3010.82.1      fBasics_3011.87       timeSeries_3022.101.2 timeDate_3012.100     rugarch_1.3-6        
[11] tsDyn_0.9-44          ccgarch_0.2.3         gdata_2.17.0          gtools_3.5.0          tidyr_0.6.0          
[16] dplyr_0.5.0          

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] rgl_0.96.0                  Rcpp_0.12.8                 mvtnorm_1.0-5               lattice_0.20-34            
 [5] zoo_1.7-14                  assertthat_0.1              digest_0.6.10               lmtest_0.9-34              
 [9] foreach_1.4.3               mime_0.5                    truncnorm_1.0-7             R6_2.2.0                   
[13] plyr_1.8.4                  tseriesChaos_0.1-13         ggplot2_2.2.0               lazyeval_0.2.0             
[17] misc3d_0.8-4                fracdiff_1.4-2              nloptr_1.0.4                SkewHyperbolic_0.3-2       
[21] Matrix_1.2-7.1              htmlwidgets_0.8             munsell_0.4.3               shiny_0.14.2               
[25] numDeriv_2016.8-1           httpuv_1.3.3                DistributionUtils_0.5-1     mnormt_1.5-5               
[29] forecast_7.3                urca_1.3-0                  mgcv_1.8-15                 htmltools_0.3.5            
[33] vars_1.5-2                  nnet_7.3-12                 Rsolnp_1.16                 multicool_0.1-10           
[37] expm_0.999-0                tibble_1.2                  quadprog_1.5-5              codetools_0.2-15           
[41] MASS_7.3-45                 GeneralizedHyperbolic_0.8-1 grid_3.3.2                  nlme_3.1-128               
[45] jsonlite_1.1                xtable_1.8-2                gtable_0.2.0                DBI_0.5-1                  
[49] magrittr_1.5                scales_0.4.1                KernSmooth_2.23-15          tseries_0.10-36            
[53] xts_0.9-7                   sandwich_2.3-4              spd_2.0-1                   iterators_1.0.8            
[57] tools_3.3.2                 ks_1.10.4                   colorspace_1.3-2            knitr_1.15.1
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you look at the [NAMESPACE](https://github.com/cran/ccgarch/blob/master/NAMESPACE) you see that `dcc.est` is commented out (it may have be replaced by `dcc.estimation` - just a guess, I've never used the package?).

This means it is not exported by the package, but [it's still there](https://github.com/cran/ccgarch/blob/master/R/R_dcc.R), only as an internal function. You can access internal functions by using 3 colons

```
ccgarch:::dcc.est
```

As it's in the [documentation](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/ccgarch/ccgarch.pdf) I think somewhere along the line of updates and releases someone forgot to remove it properly, or un-comment it again in the export list.